# FreeMarker and OSGI

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, osgi, freemarker

We have done a lot of work with building our framework using javaee and osgi. As a template system JSP was selected as the fastest and very mature.

However, we came across one very serious problem. As we use osgi, we have one web application bundle - wab. This bundle contains only jsp,css,js,images,flash + configuration xml files. All java classes are in different bundles - jar.

The problem is that as I understand delopers of jsp didn't provide access to classloader and because of that developers of java-ee can't make jsp compiler use classes outside wab file. The problem is described here - https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11208# . The java-ee developers keep silence.

With this problem it's really very diffucult to work with code as only what you can do is reflection. That's why we want to move from jsp to freemarker.

So my question - does freemarker provide all functionality to work with osgi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeMarker's template loading mechanism relies on a pluggable `TemplateLoader` implementation, so there's no impossible in that regard. Hopefully the included `TemplateLoader`-s will do anyway.

I know of a potential performance issue with class introspection (though never heard it from users, I have just spotted it in the source code): If you have multiple classes with the same name (which can more easily happen under OSGi than elsewhere), and instances of both is accessed in templates, FreeMarker will keep flushing its whole class introspection cache, because it thinks that the classes were re-loaded. That can be a performance issue, if you are unlucky.

Other than that, `freemarker.jar` known to be used in OSGi environments for a long time. It's even an OSGi bundle out of the box.